# How to generate a PEM for PKCS#8 standard

Tags: android, openssl, bouncycastle

My goal is to read a private key on Android without using Spongy/Bouncycastle. Android supports PKCS#8 out of the box (but not PKCS#1).

My server side code (using Bouncycastle) generates the key.

```
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
        kpg.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
        KeyPair pair = kpg.generateKeyPair();

        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
        PrivateKey privateKey = factory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pair.getPrivate().getEncoded()));

        ASN1InputStream asn1input = new ASN1InputStream(privateKey.getEncoded());
        PrivateKeyInfo info = PrivateKeyInfo.getInstance(asn1input.readObject());

        // write out PEM using Bouncycastle's PEMWriter
```

This generates a PKCS#1 and cannot be read in Android. However, I can take that key and run

```
openssl pkcs -topk8 -in file.pem -out newfile.pem -nocrypt
```

And I can read the resulting file from Android.

I want to be able to do this programmatically and not by using "openssl". Examples and documentation for Bouncycastle is sparse.

It's my understanding keys that start with ----- BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY ----- are PKCS#1 and ----- BEGIN PRIVATE KEY ----- are PKCS#8.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work- if you have a better way, I'd love to know.

```
   public static String generateKeyPair() {
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");

            kpg.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
            KeyPair pair = kpg.generateKeyPair();

            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keyspec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----");
            sb.append(new String(Base64.encode(keyspec.getEncoded())));
            sb.append("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----");

            return new String(Base64.encode(sb.toString().getBytes()));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`, you can use `pair.getPrivate().getEncoded()` directly.